# How to Access type="file" Input From Flask App

Tags: python, html, forms, file, flask

From my flask app, I need to access the file from the `<input type="file">`. Whether it be the file data or the actual file. I need to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ugPDx/ but without js

 thanks in advance!

Comment: You are probably looking for something like [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/).

Comment: @Detlef thank you for pointing me in the right direction ( :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have created the **static** folder and inside that folder, you have the **uploads** folder.

**upload.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask Image Upload and Display Example</title>
<h2>Select an image to upload and display</h2>
<p>
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
      {% if messages %}
        <ul class=flashes>
        {% for message in messages %}
          <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
</p>
{% if filename %}
    <div>
        <img src="{{ url_for('display_image', filename=filename) }}">
    </div>
{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <dl>
        <p>
            <input type="file" name="file" autocomplete="off" required>
        </p>
    </dl>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </p>
</form>
```

**app.py**

```
import os
import urllib.request
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for, render_template
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads/'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = "secret key"
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
app.config['MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH'] = 16 * 1024 * 1024

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = set(['png', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif'])

def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('upload.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        flash('No file part')
        return redirect(request.url)
    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        flash('No image selected for uploading')
        return redirect(request.url)
    if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
        filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
        file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
        #print('upload_image filename: ' + filename)
        flash('Image successfully uploaded and displayed')
        return render_template('upload.html', filename=filename)
    else:
        flash('Allowed image types are -> png, jpg, jpeg, gif')
        return redirect(request.url)

@app.route('/display/<filename>')
def display_image(filename):
    #print('display_image filename: ' + filename)
    return redirect(url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + filename), code=301)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: Sorry I'm late to respond, I didn't get to test it until now. I am getting the following error: `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'static/uploads/test.jpg'`. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: Did you make sure you have the static folder and the uploads folder inside the static folder? What does the flask error say? Try turning bebug mode on and check. I am unable to reproduce the error.

Comment: it was really weird, but I managed to fix the bug by moving everything to a different directory. I have no idea why it was happening, I must've done something wrong.